# How can I normalize json

Tags: python, json, pandas, pandas-datareader

I can't normalize json string looking like that:

```
{
    "Mercy": [
        [
            "Chicago",
            "New Orleans"
        ]
    ],
    "Zarya": [
        [
            "Rio de Janeiro",
            "Capetown"
        ],
        [
            "Rome",
            "Seattle"
        ]
    ],
    "Torbjörn": [
        [
            "Buenos Aires",
            "New York"
        ],
        [
            "Capetown",
            "Juneau"
        ],
        [
            "Istanbul",
            "Cairo"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I want to get the dataframe like that:
  name   city1   city2   city3   city4   city5   city6 ..... cityN
0
1
.
.
.
Is it possible?

Comment: kindly post a visual of ur expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need 2 columns DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, y) for k, v in d.items() for x in v for y in x],
                   columns=['name','city'])
print (df)
        name            city
0      Mercy         Chicago
1      Mercy     New Orleans
2      Zarya  Rio de Janeiro
3      Zarya        Capetown
4      Zarya            Rome
5      Zarya         Seattle
6   Torbjörn    Buenos Aires
7   Torbjörn        New York
8   Torbjörn        Capetown
9   Torbjörn          Juneau
10  Torbjörn        Istanbul
11  Torbjörn           Cairo
```

EDIT: If need lists in new columns use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k,*x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v])
df.columns=['name'] + [f'city{i}' for i in df.columns[1:]]
print (df)
       name           city1        city2
0     Mercy         Chicago  New Orleans
1     Zarya  Rio de Janeiro     Capetown
2     Zarya            Rome      Seattle
3  Torbjörn    Buenos Aires     New York
4  Torbjörn        Capetown       Juneau
5  Torbjörn        Istanbul        Cairo
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function `json_normalize()` in `pandas` (not sure about the correct version)

```
json_normalize(json_data)
```

It returns a flattened dataframe

Here's [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for this

That how it looks:[image: execution representation]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for you? (Your data is in the `data.json` file)

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as fil: 
     DATA = pd.read_json(fil, orient='index')

print(DATA.T)
```

Outputs:

```
           Mercy                       Zarya                  Torbjörn
0  [Chicago, New Orleans]  [Rio de Janeiro, Capetown]  [Buenos Aires, New York]
1                    None             [Rome, Seattle]        [Capetown, Juneau]
2                    None                        None         [Istanbul, Cairo]
```